# How to pass a query to mongoose and get specific data?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to Node and MongoDb, i have an object like this in the database,

```
  [{
    "_id": "5890b47a6166c457ffdee2bb",
    "description": "Capital One Beach Bash: Free Orange Bowl concert on South Beach",
    "name": "Imagine Dragons: Orange Bowl",
    "place": {
        "name": "Lummus Park, Miami Beach",
        "location": {
            "city": "Miami",
            "country": "United States",
            "latitude": 25.7804,
            "longitude": -80.1299,
            "state": "FL",
            "zip": "33139"
        },
        "id": "166795223482547",
        "_id": "5890b4956166c457ffdee46c"
    },
    "start_time": "2015-12-30T19:00:00-0500",
    "id": "730714023727940"
}]
```

I have created a schema for this above json with mongoose, i can retrieve the entire dataset using the following,

```
model.find(conditon, {}, options, function(error, data) {
}
```

How can i retrieve the top 10 events for the country "United States" ? how to write a custom query inside the condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To query nested objects you can use the [dot(.) notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation).

To get limited results you can use the [limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/method/cursor.limit/) option.

So your query will be like this -

```
model.find({'place.location.country': 'United States'}, {}, {limit: 10}, function(error, data) {});
```

Comment: Code-only answer not really helpful for all, may you please add some explanation so you help stack overflow, and beginners to learn, questions and answers not to solve problems, but to learn also.

Comment: @JyotmanSingh any idea on this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42051488/filter-by-country-and-free-text-search-mongodb-using-mongoose