# Filter by country and free text search mongodb using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have document in mongodb as follows,

[image]

My schema is as follows,

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var eventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    description: {
        type: String        
    },
    end_time: {
        type: Date      
    },
    start_time: {
        type: Date      
    },
    name: {
        type: String    
    },
    place: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Location'
    }
});
eventSchema.index({description: 'text'});
module.exports= Event;
```

I am trying to query the documents where country is "Australia" and includes text in the description "Ade". but the following query returns empty result set, whereas there are around 15 documents.

```
query : function(model, conditon,options) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            options = options||{};
            console.log("model is" + model);
            model.find(conditon, {}, options, function(error, data) {
                if (error)
                    console.log(error);
                    reject(error);               
                resolve(data);
            })
        })
    }
```

This is how i call the query,

```
dbHelper.query(mongoose.model('events'), {$text: {$search: "Ade"},'place.location.country': "Australia"},function(error,data){
                        callback(data);       
});
```

Comment: are you passing {$text: {$search: "Ade"} or {$text: {$search: "Ade"}} . ?

Comment: a glitch i noticed. this might be typo

Comment: {$text: {$search: "Ade"}

Comment: then this is unclosed object the bracket starting before $text should close

Answer (score 2):

First of all I hope you know that to perform `$text` based queries you need to have a [text based index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#op._S_text) on that particular field.

Secondly you seem to be confusing callbacks and promises -

As I can see your `query()` function is returning a promise still when you're calling the `query()` function you're expecting the callback. Promises are returned immediately to you and then you need to resolve them.

Your code should look like this -

```
dbHelper.query(mongoose.model('events'), {$text: {$search: "Ade"},'place.location.country': "Australia"})
.then(function(result)){
    // you have your data here
}
.catch(function(err)){
    // an error occured
}
```

Read more about **Promises** [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Another minor bug I can notice is in the `query()` method. The `if statement` does not use curly brace and as a result only the very next statement after the `if statement` will be executed under the `if` clause. The second statement after the `if` will always be executed -

So,

```
if(error)
    console.log(error);
// always executed
reject(error);
resolve(data);
```

should be -

```
if(error){
    console.log(error);
    reject(error);
}
resolve(data);
```

I'm still not sure all these would be able to make your code work as I can't see the whole picture here. I IMHO recommend that you invest some more time covering the javascript and MongoDB basics. Will help you save a lot of time. And for that matter MongoDB's [official docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/) are really good.

Comment: actually my existing code worked when i recreated the index. +1 for the detailed answer